# Classifying objects in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to organize a set of `Object` (`MyPlugin`) in a `TreeView` by Category.
Actually i'm adding them to the `TreeView` using the following method :

```
  internal static TreeNode AddPluginNode(TreeView parent, AbstractEnvChecker plugin)
  {
      TreeNode created = new TreeNode(plugin.Name) { Tag = plugin };
      parent.Nodes.Add(created);
      return created;
  }
```

// I'm using the `Tag` so i can conserve the `MyPlugin` `Type` for each `Node`

And this is the method i'm using to populate my `TreeView` from a `List<MyPlugin>` :

```
internal static void FillTreeViewWithPlugins(TreeView p_TreeView, Type p_Type, IList<AbstractEnvChecker> p_List)
{
    TreeNode v_TreeNode;
    if (p_TreeView != null)
    {
        p_TreeView.Nodes.Clear();
        foreach (object p_Item in p_List)
        {
            if (p_Item.GetType().IsSubclassOf(p_Type))
            {
                v_TreeNode = null;
                v_TreeNode = AddPluginNode(p_TreeView, p_Item as AbstractEnvChecker);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works well, but the problem is that the previous method displays a simple `TreeView` that contains then list of `MyPlugin`. I want to classify them by a property called `Category` (`String MyPlugin.Category`).

So i should proceed like this :

```
TreeNode testNodeA = new TreeNode("A"); 
TreeNode testNodeB = new TreeNode("B");
TreeNode testNodeC = new TreeNode("C");
TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[] { testNodeA, testNodeB, testNodeC };
TreeNode cat = new TreeNode("Categorie X", array);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(cat);
```

1. If i want to keep my previous code, i cannot know how many plugins will i add to each category so i cannot use an `Array` with fixed dimensions ...
2. I can't use `List` because the `TreeNode` constructor accepts only `Array` and the `TreeView.Nodes.Add` method accepts only `TreeNode` ...

How can i do it ?

Comment: You can use `List`. Fill it and use its `ToArray()` method to get an array of all the items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a dictionary of categories on the fly while creating the nodes. Later, add only these nodes to the tree. The steps are as follows:

Declare a dictionary like that

```
Dictionary<string, TreeNode> categoryNodes = new ...;
```

The key is the category name, the value is the `TreeNode` for the category.

While iterating over all the `MyPlugin`s in your list, check whether there's a category node in the dictionary and create one if there's not:

```
if (!categoryNodes.ContainsKey(p_Item.Category))
    categoryNodes[p_Item.Category] = new TreeNode(p_Item.Category);
```

Add the new `TreeNode` for the plugin under the respective category node:

```
v_TreeNode = AddPluginNode(categoryNodes[p_Item.Category], p_Item as AbstractEnvChecker);
```

In the end, add all the values of the dictionary to the tree:

```
foreach (string key in categoryNodes.Keys)
{
    p_TreeView.Nodes.Add(categoryNodes[key]);
}
```

Your code should look like this:

```
internal static void FillTreeViewWithPlugins(TreeView p_TreeView, Type p_Type, IList<AbstractEnvChecker> p_List)
{
    Dictionary<string, TreeNode> categoryNodes = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();
    TreeNode v_TreeNode;

    if (p_TreeView != null)
    {
        p_TreeView.Nodes.Clear();

        foreach (object p_Item in p_List)
        {
            if (p_Item.GetType().IsSubclassOf(p_Type))
            {
                if (!categoryNodes.ContainsKey(p_Item.Category))
                    categoryNodes[p_Item.Category] = new TreeNode(p_Item.Category);

                v_TreeNode = null;
                v_TreeNode = AddPluginNode(categoryNodes[p_Item.Category], p_Item as AbstractEnvChecker);    
            }
        }

        foreach (string cat in categoryNodes.Keys)
            p_TreeView.Nodes.Add(categoryNodes[cat]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with `AddPluginNode(TreeView parent, AbstractEnvChecker plugin)` method ... `categoryNodes[p_Item.Category]` should be a `TreeView` ...

Comment: Or `categoryNodes[p_Item.Category]` should be a `List` with the new signature ...

Comment: The error in the `foreach` loop was caused because I forgot to add `.Keys` - modified my answer. Of course you need to change the `AddPluginNode` to not accept a `TreeView` but a `TreeNode`.

Comment: Even though this approach is more flexible...?